# Mvvmcross for Universal Windows - why do I have to delete LoadState and SaveState

Tags: windows-runtime, mvvmcross, win-universal-app

Referring to this document:

https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/Tip-Calc-A-Universal-Windows-App-UI-Project

Why do I have to delete those functions?

How should I manage state saving and loading without them?

Answer (score 3):

Generally you would use the *SaveState* and *ReloadState* methods on your ViewModel. This is the cross-platform way of maintaining state.

See https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/View-Model-Lifecycle

I use platform specific Save/Load State methods for saving UI specific data like scroll position or current tab, etc.